# UIImagePicker - white square frame comes up in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController and I let the user pick an image. When they tap an image, a white square frame comes up, and the image they selected can be moved around or zoomed in/out, but the portion of the image that is captured and returned from

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

is the portion in the white square, which seems to always be 320x480

Can I let the user select an entire image? I would like to let them select an entire image, but then scale it to 320x480 if it is larger than 320x480.

Can someone show me example code for this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen, though it shows that square, the entire image is selected. iOS 4 behavior.

You can also disable editing

```
picker.allowsEditing = FALSE;
```

Comment: okay, that fixed it from always coming in as 640x640 due to the white square. but now I have another issue. The native iPhone camera takes photos and makes them landscape, even though they look portrait in the photo app. When they come into the imagePickerController method, if it is iPhone picture, it's landscape. how can I know what is landscape so I know to make it portrait so that I can display it properly?

Comment: Sounds like a different question. I would request you to post a different question. If your original question is answered, please mark this answer correct. Thanks.